# Can return connection object inside a try with resources

Tags: java, java-7

I have connection provider class as bleow to return connection.

```
 public class ConnectionProvider {

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection ConnectDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {  

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspservlet_test","root", "root");
                ) {

            return connection;
        }           
    }
}
```

Here is main method to call connection provider.

```
public void Test() {

        try {               
            Connection con =  ConnectionProvider.ConnectDB();

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("");                            

        } catch (SQLException e) {          

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But **"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed."** error are always show at below line of code.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("");
```

Because, according to Oracle documentation, If use try with resources java 7 features, resources are auto close after try block even it's errors occurred or not. So even I returned the connection it's already closed.

Let me know, my usage logic is wrong?
How can I return this connection inside try with resource?
I tried many time googling for solution but does not get convenience answers for me.

Let me know your suggestion and feedback please.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with try-with-resources here?

Comment: Just remove try-with-resources from `ConnectDB()` and use it in `Test()`.

Comment: @defaultlocale , goal is clear, to provide connection object to callers. you wanna mean it's not good?

Comment: @YeWin to provide connection, you just need to return it. Why do you have try-with-resources there? I'm just trying to understand

Comment: @defaultlocale , may be my bad idea is afraid for connection is not closed in ConnectionProvider class because I never try connection close in caller Test() method. Just return connection can close in caller method when it finished?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to close connection afterwards manually

Comment: I can close connection in Test method via manually/trywithresources. But I just want to know return connection from ConnectionProvider class can close connection?

Answer (score 2):

#### What you can't do...

With a `try-with-resources` as you have it after you `return` the connection you `return`(d) is close(d). You **can't** return the connection from inside the try with resources.

#### What you can do...

Pass the `connection` (inside your `try-with-resources`) to a method that takes a `connection`. You can also use a ConnectionPool, and get the `Connection` when you need it (to create and execute a query).

Comment: could you please provide more for "What you can do..." ??

Comment: Could you please provide more for query than `""`??

Comment: it's BL dependent. It will be set DML, DQL operation there. There will be many Test method in program and will call the connection return method.

Comment: Not the way you're going about it. You asked what you can do. I've answered you. If you want a more specific answer, ask a more specific question. As it is, use a Connection Pool and be done with it.

Comment: Ok,   I understand and I just want to know more ways . Thanks for your answer and I will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

*Let me know, my usage logic is wrong?*

The usage of 'try-with-resources' logic is wrong in this context, because the intention of `ConnectDB()` is to return a connection instance which could be actually used by the caller to send a SQL statement, but instead, the connection instance is getting auto-closed, before it could be used by the caller, because of using '*try-with-resources*' construct of Java.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick how-to on try-with-resource and JDBC**

Your ConnectionProvider's ConnectDB *already declares* it is throwing SQLException - so no need to catch it in here: (You should consider replacing this code with connection pool maybe)

```
public class ConnectionProvider {
    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Connection ConnectDB() throws SQLException {  
      return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jspservlet_test","root", "root");
    }
}
```

Instead use try-with-resource in your test-class to clean up your code and focus on errors your SQL code
might have:

```
public void Test() {

    try (Connection con =  ConnectionProvider.ConnectDB();
         PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT 1")) {
         //Prepare your Statement
         ps.setInt(1, 1);
         //And another try-with-resource for the result - note the closing brace
         try(ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while(rs.next()) {
               //Handle your Result
               System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
         } // This closes try-with-resource. Exception will be rethron to be caught in outer catch!          
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        //SQL is Broken - but only ONE catch to catch them all
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

That way you gain

- Better readability for your code (no calls to close surrounded by finally and if != null)
- Centralized error handling if anything in your SQL code breaks (so you can focus on functional error of "statement didn't run")
- Better code quality: No need to worry about Cursors, Statements, Connections not being propery closed.